Geometric difference between the straight lines $ax+by = 0$ between $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $\gcd(a, b) \neq 1 $?
Suppose $ax+by = 0$. For fixed $a$ and $b$, the equation gives a straight line in 2D passing through the origin. Different $a$ and $b$ give different straight lines (not always). Is there any geometric difference between the straight lines when $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ and when $\gcd(a, b) \neq 1 $? If yes, what is that?
I have no clue. Any help is appreciated.

Let me show you two equations:
$$3x + 2y = 0$$
$$6x + 4y = 0$$
In the first equation: $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.
In the second equation: $\gcd(a,b) = 2$.
... and yet, they are two equations of exactly the same straight line :-)
